# Проактивный телеграм бот на c#, отправка сообщения в заданное время

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать телеграм бота, которому юзер кидает какую - то привычку(например, пить воду) и определенное время, когда бот должен пересылать юзеру это сообщение. Такой вот бот - привычка. Фишка в том, что я не совсем понимаю, какая должна быть логика, чтобы бот мог отправлять сообщения именно в заданное время + возможна такая опция, как повтор дней или недели.
Посему прошу помощи, как бы лучше написать, да и как бы вообще написать эту механику.

UPD. Возможно какое - то решение через список Task, с отложенным временем действия

Comment: Смотрите логику работу и исходники `cron`, `crontab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего понадобится библиотека типа Quartz.
И как только некий юзер добавляет напоминалку, нужно будет ее добавить в кварц.

Кварц же когда наступит некое время - вызовет метод типа SendTeleMessage(string user, string message); внутри которого реализована логика посылания сообщения...

или что-то такое :)

---

> UPD. Возможно какое - то решение через список Task, с отложенным временем действия

Есть такая штука как TaskScheduler.  Можешь реализовать через него. Но не уверен что это хорошее решение.

Comment: Боюсь, что использование сторонних библиотек не предусмотрено моим заданием, к тому же все должно быть проще реализовано

Comment: Это, как раз, самый простой способ. Любой другой способ без библиотек -- это будет уже изобретание велосипеда и более сложная реализация.

Comment: Преподаватель того и требует, дабы студенты не пользовали сторонние библиотеки

Comment: ну тогда TaskScheduler

Comment: А можно какую - нибудь информацию о том, как он сможет,например, параллельно ждать и принимать сообщения от юзера ?

Comment: у тебя есть ивент который генерируется при сообщении от юзера. На этот ивент нужно подписать функцию которая анализирует сообщение юзера, вытаскивая одтуда нужную информацию и создает таску в TaskScheduler на нужное время. Подход тот же самый, что и с кварцом.

Answer (score 0):

Немного костыльный метод, но он вам подойдет.

Вы можете вести sql бд и каждую минуту опрашивать, ли же построить логику, когда вы будите получать ближайшие задачи.

Оба варианта должны вам подойти, поскольку, сверх большой производительности (несколько тысяч напоминаний покормить кота в 18:05) от бота, вы не получите. Из-за [ограничения в 20 сообщений в минуту](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users).

Comment: Второй вариант мне больше подходит, но не совсем понимаю

Comment: Опрашиваете бд о предстоящих задачах на следующие 10 минут > получаете, условно, 500 напоминаний от разных по уровню клиентов> сортируете их по важности клиента  или напоминания (вы не сможете моментально отправить сообщения всем, поэтому нужны приоритеты) > и постепенно отправляете